# dual screen doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, 64-bit, resolution

I'm not an expert in Linux but I'm currently try to learn it myself. Unfortunately I'm stuck here.

So, I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit ( with Unity desktop ) on a laptop.

I get stuck when I try to plug another screen to run Linux in dual screen mode.I configured display( with user-friendly control panel : settings->display ) in dual boot mode and when I want to apply I get this error message :

```
La configuration d'affichage sélectionnée ne peut pas être appliquée.
la taille virtuelle demandée n'est pas adaptée à la taille disponible : demande=(2800, 900), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1440, 1440)
```

I'm french and so is my Linux.

My graphic card is Mobility Radeon HD 5430 Series, so I have downloaded and installed last drivers from ATI web site but it does not resolve my problem.

I even tried searching on Google with my error message and tried the methods listed but it could not solve the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Just tell me if you need more information.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the version of ubuntu as well.

Comment: Try to use the ATI / AMD Tool that comes with the driver you have installed. I only have used NVIDIA Cards with Ubuntu, but the Nvidia sometimes works better for me ...

Answer (score 3):

When you open your system connect that to internet and open 'Additional Drivers' application.....It shows the available drivers for system hardware ........ Install from there and restart your system.......

Comment: hello, I profite to be on windows and to have access to my michael luis account to let you a comment. I have tried your solution and alert that not fixing my problem but I was not using this account but my tyd01 account. So maybe my log can give you more precision about what is not working

Answer (score 1):

it's me who open this subject some days ago, I have just change my account during this time.

I was very busy during this period, and I was not coming back on this page to see your propositions...

So today I have tried to use additional drivers. When I open additional drivers window, there is two of this which are proposed ( sorry it's French ) :

- Pilote propriétaire ATI/AMD pour carte graphique FGLRX.
- Pilotes graphiques FGLRX propriétaires ATI/AMD (mises à jour postérieures à la sortie d'Ubuntu)

I succeed to install the first one but it does not resolve my problem.

When I try to install the second one, I got an error and system tell me to show /var/log/jockey.log for more details. And it disable the first driver.

like log is very fat and this message is limited to 30000 characters I post it in 2 parts :

part 1:

```
2012-12-07 14:30:52,080 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:30:52,080 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:31:02,479 DEBUG: Installing package: fglrx-updates
2012-12-07 14:31:04,288 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 0.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:08,493 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 0.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:08,582 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 6.250000
2012-12-07 14:31:08,582 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 12.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:08,933 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 18.750000
2012-12-07 14:31:09,355 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 18.750000
2012-12-07 14:31:09,455 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 25.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:29,334 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 31.250000
2012-12-07 14:31:30,070 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:30,187 DEBUG: install progress bamfdaemon 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:30,348 DEBUG: install progress ureadahead 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:30,490 DEBUG: install progress initramfs-tools 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:43,605 DEBUG: install progress libc-bin 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:44,712 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:45,413 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 37.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:45,414 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 43.750000
2012-12-07 14:31:52,134 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 50.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:52,210 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 56.250000
2012-12-07 14:31:52,431 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 56.250000
2012-12-07 14:31:52,531 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 62.500000
2012-12-07 14:31:53,147 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 68.750000
2012-12-07 14:31:53,226 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 75.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:53,299 DEBUG: install progress ureadahead 75.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:53,650 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 75.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:53,704 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 75.000000
2012-12-07 14:31:54,072 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 81.250000
2012-12-07 14:32:15,225 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 87.500000
2012-12-07 14:32:15,586 DEBUG: install progress bamfdaemon 87.500000
2012-12-07 14:32:15,811 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 87.500000
2012-12-07 14:32:15,887 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 93.750000
2012-12-07 14:32:15,954 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 100.000000
2012-12-07 14:32:16,030 DEBUG: install progress initramfs-tools 100.000000
2012-12-07 14:32:27,078 DEBUG: install progress libc-bin 100.000000
2012-12-07 14:32:28,984 DEBUG: (Reading database ... 263745 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fglrx-amdcccle ...
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx-amdcccle, directory '/usr/share/ati' not empty so not removed.
Removing fglrx ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Virtual` with parameter `2800 900` line is required in `Display` subsection of your xorg.conf configuration file.

See xorg.conf manpage for details

Answer (score 0):

part 2 :

```
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdcccle because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdcccle (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdcccle.desktop because associated file /usr/share/fglrx/amdcccle.desktop (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdccclesu.desktop because associated file /usr/share/fglrx/amdccclesu.desktop (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdxdg-su because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdxdg-su (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules with a link.
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules with a link.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates.
(Reading database ... 263473 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx-updates (from .../fglrx-updates_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-updates.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-updates (from .../fglrx-amdcccle-updates_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up fglrx-updates (2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-updates-8.960 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.2.0-34-generic
Done.

fglrx_updates:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

2012-12-07 14:32:29,287 WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx_updates/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx_updates driver
2012-12-07 14:32:49,638 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:49,639 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:49,666 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:49,667 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:53,753 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:53,754 DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
2012-12-07 14:32:53,993 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:53,994 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:54,021 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,022 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:54,081 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,082 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:54,110 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,110 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:54,179 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,179 DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
2012-12-07 14:32:54,428 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,429 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:54,456 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:54,456 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-12-07 14:32:58,876 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-12-07 14:32:58,877 DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
```